# VBA encoding the Arabic latter

Tags: vba, csv, excel

Hi..

I have the below code to copy data from TXT file to Excel file .. the issue is some of the data contain arabic latter and the below result is came " ط¨ط´ط±ظٹط©  "

so how can encoding the result to be arabic.

```
Fname = TempFile
If fsoSheet.FileExists(Fname) = False Then Exit Sub

iRow = 2

Set file2 = fsoSheet.OpenTextFile(Fname, ForReading,true)

Do While Not file2.AtEndOfStream
    Record = file2.ReadLine
    P = Split(Record,",") 

    For iCol = 1 To 8   

'   msgbox("COL"& p(icol)- 1)

        ExcelSheet.Application.Cells(iRow, iCol) = P(iCol- 1)

    Next

    iRow = iRow + 1

Loop



file2.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional parameter at the end of the [OpenTextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) that can indicate to open the text file as Unicode:

```
Set file2 = fsoSheet.OpenTextFile(Fname, ForReading,true, TristateTrue)
```

Note: TristateTrue is a constant equal to -1.